# Multiple Case conditions in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a table where there 2 columns. F1 and F2. Now F1 has Id and F2 has score.

```
F1 Score
1   10
1   20
6   10
```

now I want to have a where clause where it considers 6 as 1 and adds them with 1

for example when I use when F1=1 it should give

```
 F1 Score
    1   10
    1   20
    1   10
```

I have used

> WHERE (F1  = CASE WHEN F1  =6 THEN  1 ELSE F1 END )

but not working.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` _expressions_ in `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: well actually the parameter I am getting is 1 .. I need to convert the 6 in the column to 1 from the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select (case when f1 = 6 then 1 else f1 end) as new_f1,
       score
from t
order by new_f1;
```

EDIT:

You changed the question.  For filtering, you would simply do:

```
where f1 in (1, 6)
```

Comment: Sorry.. But I need to use the where condition with case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select (case when F1 = 6 then 1 else F1 end) as something, SCORE 
from your_table
```